# select element with classname a also has another classname b

Tags: jquery

I have two div both have same class name `type`, I want to select the div has `type` also has classname `a`,

Now I'm using `filter` it works, but I'm wondering why can't I use `hasClass`?
I get console.log TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('.type').hasClass('.a').show()'). did I code something wrong?

```
$('.a').click(function(){
    $('.type').hasClass('a').show();
});


<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a type"></div>

<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b type"></div>
```

Comment: .hasClass isn't a filtering function, it's a getter. It returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why attempt more complicated ways when you can simply select multiple classes in one go:

`$('.type.a').show();`

[**jsFiddle example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3guXc/1/)

---

Example code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="a type">a type</div>

<div class="b">b </div>
<div class="b type">b type</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.type {
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.a').click(function(){
    $('.a.type').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select them straight away:

```
$('.classOne.classTwo')
```